# What's with the edit spam lately?

Tags: support, editing

Whenever I login to EESE (admittedly not as often as I should lately) I almost always see a notice in my inbox that leads to one of my questions that was edited, clearly by a spambot. I don't have edit rights (rep isn't high enough yet) but so far these have been caught by other community members have stepped in and marked the edits as spam (thanks editors). This only occurs with my EESE questions as far as I can tell and I was wondering how far spread it is? Do others see this occur with their questions? Is this an issue that StackExchange can resolve?

Comment: We're [enhancing the spam protection system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210201/protected-questions-and-editing/210232#210232) to deal with this specifically. The issue was the spam coming from a large distributed network.

Answer (score 1):

I had regular spam on one of my answers. I ended up locking that question so it couldn't be edited any longer. Are you seeing spam issues on a specific question/answer only? If so, post the link and I'll lock it down.

StackExchange has a number of methods in place to keep spam down... Here are a couple older answers that give you an idea:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2768
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/12760/200061

Comment: No, it's seemingly random and I only see them when I see a note in my inbox. If I see one again I'll send you a link to it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this has increased, but I've definitely rejected a fair few spam edits.

Luckily, since EESE doesn't let users edit posts until they have built up some rep, all edits go into a moderation queue, so one of our members has a chance to review and reject it before it is ever displayed to the public.